# How can I read a magic number from file?

Tags: c

I have a list of files. For each of those files, I need to find out if the starting two chars are - '#!'. How do I do this?

Comment: Read the two characters.  Check that the first is '#' and the second is '!'.

Comment: `#!` doesn't look like a number to me... not even magical one.

Comment: I tried, but I get confusing symbols.

Comment: Tried *what*? We don't know what have you tried, thus cannot tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. #! is magic number used in shell script see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: @alessiovolpe we know what #! means. We dont know what you tried that gave you 'confusing symbols' - show some code.

Comment: @alessiovolpe  That's not what a magic number is. That's more of a header. A magic number is something like [0xCAFEBABE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) or 0x1BADB002 for GRUB.

Comment: @MDXF Well, technically speaking '#!' is a number you know..

Comment: Just use fgetc(FILE*) to get the first two characters, and then compare them with '#' and '!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the two numbers using `fgetc()` (as @WilliamPursell suggested) and then compare them:

```
int i1, i2;
FILE *file;

file = fopen("yourfile", "rb");
if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Error: failed to open file");
    return 1;
}
i1 = fgetc(file);
i2 = fgetc(file);

// 23h...#, 21h...!
if (i1 == 0x23 && i2 == 0x21) {
    // magic number
}
```

Comment: Perhaps check the return value from `fopen`

Comment: I omitted it on purpose, since it is not the focus of the question.

Comment: I thought writing bug free code is also the focus of the question

Comment: Not my DV but better check the type returned by `fgetc`. It is not `char`. Nor are `'#'` or `'!'` of type `char`.

Comment: You can use '#' instead of the hex values - makes the code readable

Comment: Using 0x23 and 0x21 is silly.